# É possível fazer atribuição a primeira coluna de uma linha de um/a vector/matriz?

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, matriz, vector

tendo como exemplo um vetor de duas dimensões do tipo `char` 2x2:

```
char vet[2][2];
```

é possivel fazer atribuição para os indices da primeira linha desse vetor?
ou eles funcionam tipo um ponteiro para as demais linhas e colunas?

eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void){
    char v2[2][2];
    v2[0] = 'a'; // LINHA 10
    v2[1] = 'c'; // LINHA 11
    printf("%c\t%c", v2[0], v2[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

o compilador esta me retornando 2 erros na linha 10 e 11

> assignment to expression whit array type

por fim o codigo não compila

Comment: Eu acho que o compilador discorda sobre quem é a linha 10...

Comment: Meu comentário anterior ficou obsoleto depois da edição =]

Comment: que eu vinha fazendo muita edição no codigo acabou passando despercebido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assanges, você tem que ter em mente que quando você está trabalhando com matrizes você precisa passar o endereço completo da posição à qual quer fazer uma atribuição. A declaração e uso de matriz e vetor são diferentes.

```
char vet[2]; //Isso é um vetor de duas posições
char matriz[2][5]; //Isso é uma matriz com 2 linhas e 5 colunas
```

Logo, conceitualmente podemos representar a disposição dos elementos na memória da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um fun fact sobre a matriz com o qual normalmente não precisamos nos preocupar na programação para PC é que embora haja essa disposição "teórica" dos elementos em formato de matriz, os elementos na verdade são dispostos em espaços de memória de forma sequencial, ou seja, para o exemplo acima matriz[ 1 ][ 0 ] na memória vem logo após matriz[ 0 ][ 4 ]

Mais uma fato sobre matrizes é que quando você faz referência a ela desta forma "matriz[ 1 ]" você está apontando para o valor do endereço  de memória.
Pode testar com o exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void){
    char v2[2][5];
    printf("%d", v2[0]); //Imprimirá um número X
    printf("\n%d\n", v2[1]); //Imprimirá um número X+5, pois a linha 0 tem 5 colunas

    return 0;
}
```

Mas enfim, para atribuir um valor a uma posição da matriz você precisa passar a posição de forma completa. Exemplo:

```
char matriz[2][3];
matriz[1][2] = 'a';
```

O resultado seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Gabriel, tem a referência falando que a matriz é alçada continuamente? Eu também creio nisso, mas não consegui resgatar essa referência quando escrevi minha resposta, portanto achei melhor não por lá

Comment: @Gabriel Magri eu só não acho que esse tipo de ilustração de uma matriz funcionaria para uma matriz tridimensional  eg matriz[3][4][6]

Comment: @Assanges, exatamente, essa representação é para uma matriz bidimensional apenas.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, você pode fazer o teste para comprovar de forma experimental, conforme citei ali na resposta.
O livro "C Completo e Total" de Herbert Schildt explica isso de uma forma diferente na página 106. Ele diz que, por exemplo, em uma matriz a de 10 por 10 o elemento [0][4] pode ser referenciado de duas formas, a[0][2] ou *(a+2) enquanto o elemento [1][2] pode ser referenciado também de duas formas, a[1][2] ou *(a+12).

Comment: C cometo e total? Ok, tem um desafio na internet que era tentar descobrir uma página dele sem erros. Mais referência: http://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn3e.html http://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html#pages https://www.quora.com/Which-book-is-better-Herbert-Schildts-C-The-complete-reference-or-Ritchie-and-Kerninghans-The-C-programming-language/answer/Madhusudhan-Srikkanth?share=ad697c76&srid=hPI1b; se esse pedaço de informação não for definido pela linguagem, isso significa que qualquer compilador por interpretar da maneira que desejar, o que significa que esse experimento tem graves falhas metodológicas

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado interessante. Vou dar uma olhada depois com mais calma.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você bota `v2[0]` ou `v2[1]`, você ainda não está se referindo a um caracter. Para se referir a um caracter, você precisa por os dois índices, como `v2[0][0]`, ou `v2[1][0]`.

O tipo `char[2][]` precisa de dois índices para ser transformado em `char`. Só por um único índice vai obter uma referência a uma região de memória que não pode ter atribuição, por isso que ele reclama que a atribuição a um `array` não pode ocorrer.

---

Por sinal, as mensagens parecem se referir às linhas:

```
v2[0] = 'a';
v2[1] = 'c';
```

já que na linha da impressão não tem atribuição nela.

Comment: bom mas quando eu defino v[1] e tento atribuir pega e quando eu defino vet[1][1] e tento atribuir so ao primeiro tipo vet[0] = 'c'; não pega pq?

Comment: @Assanges perdão, não entendi.

Comment: `char v1[2]; v1[0] = 'a';` versus `char v2[2][2]; v2[0][0] = '1';`. Algo nesse sentido?

Comment: sim esses dois exemplos acima funcionam mas se eu tentar atribuir só ao primeiro índice cru não pega levando em consideração o exemplo acima: char v2[2][2]; se eu tentar atribuir só ao índice não funciona tipo v2[0] = '1'; não pega agora se eu fizer  v2[0][0] = '1'; pega emfim essa é minha duvida os índice funcionam só como tipo um ponteiro para os demais ou também é possível fazer atribuição a eles?

Comment: Exatamente os motivos que isso acontece eu tenho algumas dúvidas, não queria por como resposta para não falar errado. Se não me engano, quando se cria uma matriz multidimensional, se aloca um único espaço de memória e a posição `1,0` dessa matriz é transformado em uma adição de um offset ao endereço da matriz. Tipo, nesse exemplo de duas colunas por linha, o endereço seria `addr(v2) + (1 * 2 + 0)`, onde o `(1 * 2 + 0)` seria o offset

Comment: @Assanges , veja esse link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm ; nele, tem o seguinte exemplo: `int a[3][4] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};`, indicando que a matriz em C é de fato um conjunto contínuo de memória e que a posição `2,3` na matriz equivale à posição `2*4 + 3 = 11`

Comment: intrigante realmente